# 2012R2 Hyper-v host CentOS7 guest slow network speed over external network

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, centos7, netcat, time-machine

I have a Hyper-V host on win2012R2 (Version 6.3.9600) with two gigabit network adapters, one of them connecting to a gigabit router (the another one is currently out of use because lack of a gigabit switch near to the server yet).

I'm running a CentOS 7 guest to run netatalk as a TimeMachine service for my Mac.

I use the network adapter on the guest as an external bridge to my router (normal virtual network adapter, not legacy (!)).

My problem is if I running a network bandwidth test between the host and the guest i just get 10MB/s (if I run python's speedtest-cli on the guest I got 153MB/s and on the host 240MB/s regarding to my broadband).

The commands I use:
Hyper-V host:

```
nc -v -l 2222 > NUL
```

And the CentOS7 guest:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k count=1024 | nc -v 192.168.250.195 2222
```

If I set up an internal virtual network adapter between the host and the guest I get 130MB/s-300MB/s with the same commands.

The guest has dynamic memory starting at 512MB, and 2 of the 4 CPU cores, but I don't thinks this matters in this case.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k count=1024 | md5sum
```

Gives 85MB/s-120MB/s

And a normal

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024k count=1024
```

Gives 350-450MB/s (Dynamic VHDX on a SATA3 disk)

How could it be? And what can I do for it? I've already ordered a gigabit switch to use the second physical network interface only for the guest but I'm afraid that this isn't the main cause of this error.

Unfortunately I not have been able to run dd over netcat from my mac to the guest because I haven't been at home for couple of days.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hi Ewert, what is the vendor and model of your Ethernet NIC?

Comment: Hi, they are Realtek® 8111G

Comment: Are Virtual Machine Queues enabled on the physical adapter in host network properties? This must be supported by the NIC and it appears it is not in the case of the RTL8111G, could be causing performance problems.

Comment: Yeah that can be a problem, but VMQ is unneccesary for this host, because only this CentOS guest needs much traffic. The couple other guest are used for monitoring via snmp.

Comment: I'll give a try to the another NIC in SR-IOV mode without host sharing, gaved only to the CentOs guest as soon as i'm phisically near to the server and when I got the new switch. Or maybe I'll setup NIC teaming between the to apadters.

Comment: Well, I finally got the new switch, but that is not what solved the problem. I've found out, that I've given static IP for the CentOS guest, as usual, but when i've tried a same instance of this guest with DHCP networking, and ran dd, it was be able to use the gigabit network (113MB/s). When I switched to static ip, I got 100Mbits again. It's really strange, but it is working now properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but with DHCP networking it's running w/ gigabit speed. With static IP it got 100Mbits again.

But it's working.